# Show specific category on Magento 1.9.2.3 Homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have gone through many posts here and on other sites where they specify using code:

```
{{block type=”catalog/product_list” name=”home.catalog.product.list” alias=”products_homepage” category_id=”4″ template=”catalog/product/custom_list.phtml”}}
```

To display a category in a block on my homepage , but it never works.  I'm running Magento 1.9.2.3 with the default rwd theme.

Thanks

Comment: Does that work with the native `catalog/product/list.phtml` file ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to...

Comment: I found out that since the latest updates you have to go into System > Permissions > Blocks. For me I had to add Catalogu/product_new for new permissions.

Comment: feel free to answer your own question and mark your question as solved or close it as it went away on its own

Answer (score 1):

Along with the above code on your specific CMS page.  You have to add an additional permission to the block system.  In order for it to work in the latest 1.9.x.x version. You have to go into System > Permissions > Blocks.

For me I had to add Catalogue/product_new for new permissions.